# How to use object(json) with AggregateFunction?

Tags: clickhouse

Basically I have a json field in a table and want to pass the most recent value to AggregatedMergeTree field via materialized view.

Unfortunately, I get the following type error:

```
 DB::Exception: Conversion from AggregateFunction(argMax, Tuple(_dummy UInt8), DateTime) to AggregateFunction(argMax, Object('json'), DateTime) is not supported: ... (CANNOT_CONVERT_TYPE) (version 23.4.1.1943 (official build))
```

I guess the reason is that `Object('json')` is `tuple` under the hood, but with fluctuating content, and function's signature is somewhat constant.

Nevertheless I'm wondering what's the right way to get around it.

```
CREATE TABLE raw (
  user_id           String,
  created_at        DateTime,
  value             JSON
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY (created_at, user_id)
```

```
CREATE TABLE state (
  user_id           String,
  _value            AggregateFunction(argMax, JSON, DateTime)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
```

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW state_mv TO state AS
  SELECT
    user_id,
    argMaxState(raw.value, raw.created_at) AS _value
  FROM raw
  GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: IMHO you can't use JSON as is in argMaxState, only scalar types with combination of JSONExtract(raw.value,'...') or JSON_QUERY ...

Comment: Slach, I see, but what's the right way to get around? cast to string? cast to array?

Comment: what you try to achieve?
you need `latest` JSON value for max created_at?
it looks like similar `ENGINE=ReplcaingMergeTree(created_at) ORDER BY user_id`

Comment: @Slach Fair question. I'm looking for two things: uniqueness guarantee and fast search by json fields in value. As far as I can see, `ReplacingMergeTree` doesn't provide such one. Nonetheless, I came up with a solution by means of `DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came up with the following solution:

```
CREATE TABLE raw (
  user_id           String,
  created_at        DateTime,
  expiring_at       DateTime,
  value_raw         String
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY (created_at, user_id, expiring_at)
```

```
CREATE TABLE state (
  user_id           String,
  value             JSON DEFAULT cast(finalizeAggregation(_value_raw), 'String'),
  _expiring_at      AggregateFunction(argMax, DateTime, DateTime),
  _value_raw        AggregateFunction(argMax, String, DateTime)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
TTL finalizeAggregation(_expiring_at)
```

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW state_mv TO state AS
  SELECT
    user_id,
    argMaxState(raw.expiring_at, raw.created_at) AS _expiring_at,
    argMaxState(raw.value_raw, raw.created_at)   AS _value_raw
  FROM raw
GROUP BY user_id
```